# Accessing application objects from Windows Runtime Component (Background service)

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross, background-task

Having a UWP application with BackgroundTask project.

I defined the background task in the manifest and registered it successfully.
The problem is when the task is running

```
public sealed class MediaFilesScanTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var defferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        var settings = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<ISettingsService>();

        ...
    }
```

I cannot access any objects from my app.
In that case, Mvx.IoCProvider is null, although I registered ISettingsService.
I also tried a static class instead of using IoC, but even with that the class is null...

I'm running the task manually, through VS in LifeCycle Events.

Comment: Any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your background task runs in a different context in which the `IoCProvider` has not yet been initialized. Try using `MvxIoCProvider.Initialize();`.